# How do I match an entire line in Notepad++ for search/replace?

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I'd like to do a bulk line-by-line replace on a file within Notepad++ like so:

```
This is my line of text that I would like to replace
```

to

```
"This is my line of text that I would like to replace" +
```

I tried the following:

Find:  `^$`    Replace: `"\1" +`

Find:  `^()$`    Replace: `"\1" +`

Find:  `(^$)`    Replace: `"\1" +`

Any hints?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to search for `^(.*)$` and replace with `"\1" +`

The difference between this and your's is that this one captures all characters between the starting and ending of the string. Your regexes simply tries to capture nothing.

Comment: This did exactly what I need.  I appreciate the explanation as to why mine was wrong as well!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Find: ^(.*?)$

Replace: "\1" +
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What is the purpose of the question mark in the Find expression?

Comment: It makes the search `lazy`. In this particularly case it does not have any affect on the search though.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Find `(.*)` replace `"\1" +`

Comment: This also does what I need.  I'm guessing the ^ and the $ can be omitted in my case because Notepad++ does regexes line by line.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works for you:

Find: ^(.+)$
Replace: "\1" +